# phpbb variable empty on custom page

Tags: phpbb3

I have a phpbb 3.1 forum, where I have put a html portal, (using the custom page tutorial)

I have included functions.php so I can use `{S_USERNAME}` and everything with the S_ in that page...

but, now I want to put the forum statistics, using, for example:

```
{TOTAL_USERS_ONLINE}        
{LOGGED_IN_USER_LIST}
{TOTAL_POSTS}
```

and so on

The variables, are empty when using them in my page... is there any problem? I need to add something more than that file?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The variables are mentioned are initialized in the `page_header` function in `functions.php`

In custom pages you always call that function to initialize common variables like the `S_` variables you mentioned.

Since the loading of online users is a little heavier and not needed on every page, the function has a parameter `$display_online_list` to enable it.

Check the [method signature](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/3f5a873e4cff0fd6f9ab2dd4fad1179009abed4b/phpBB/includes/functions.php#L4935) and set `$display_online_list` to `true`

To display `TOTAL_POSTS`, you will need to add a bit of code, see the `assign_vars` call in [index.php](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/3f5a873e4cff0fd6f9ab2dd4fad1179009abed4b/phpBB/index.php#L198), `$config` is a global variable which should be available in every page.